# Low pass filter output

Tags: signal-analysis, continuous-signals, lowpass-filter, filtering

What will be the output when a square wave of time period 1sec is applied to the input of LPF of cutoff frequency 1Hz. Please help me, I am not getting the exact expression. What if cutoff of LPF is increased to 4Hz.

Comment: This looks like homework.  Go ahead and *edit your question* to both share the problem as given to you, and to show us the work you've done.

Comment: @TimWescott , Sir I found the Fourier series representation of square wave and found only the first harmonic will get pass through the LPF. So the o/p has to be a sine wave but I am not confident.

Comment: So the filter is *specifically* defined as having $H(f) = 1\ \forall\ |f| \le 1$ and $H(f) = 0\ \forall\ |f| > 1$?

Comment: @TimWescott Yes Sir